# How to make a copy of a QuickSight analysis?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

This *must* be a silly question. I know how to do a "save as" for a dashboard (don't really need that, but any way). But now I have a analysis with a lot of settings (parameters & filters) and want to reuse my work in a new analyses. But how do I make a copy, save as, or similar ?

Answer (score 19):

Steps to create copy of an Analysis in QuickSight:

1. Go to your existing Analysis in QuickSight.
2. Create a Dashboard and publish it.
3. Return to QuickSight home page and navigate to Dashboard page and open the Dashboard that you just created.
4. Click on "Save As" button on top right corner of the QuickSight window.
5. It will allow to create a new Analysis from this Dashboard.
6. There, you now have a copy of the original Analysis!

Comment: I'm not seeing a Save-As, can you recheck it still works or post a screenshot?  I only have Data, Share, Region, and Username in the top-right of a dashboard.

Comment: @Ian you need the right permissions :
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/copying-a-dashboard.html