# How to make a copy of the Quicksight analysis used by dashboard?

Tags: amazon-quicksight

This is **NOT** a duplicate question.

I have checked Stack Overflow and have found instances of people asking the same question:

- [How to make a copy of a QuickSight analysis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55010723/how-to-make-a-copy-of-a-quicksight-analysis/55552314#55552314)
- [Copy AWS QuickSight analysis to another account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58298581/copy-aws-quicksight-analysis-to-another-account)

The solutions provided for these questions refer to the "Save as" options at the top of the dashboard screen or the "Share" option at the top of the analysis screen. The issue is that these options are not available to me.  I have admin access but I am unable to Share/Save as.
How am I able to reuse the analysis used by my dashboard?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation ("Sharing an Existing Dashboard")](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/sharing-a-dashboard.html), in order to see the "Save As" icon you must be either a co-owner of the dashboard or have the "Save As" privileges. The "Save As" privileges are granted by the owner of the dashboard in the UI, in the "Manage dashboard access" overlay.

I think either way you need to contact the creator of the dashboard - annoyingly I couldn't find a way to control this using the API.

Answer (score 2):

If the UI controls aren't available to you, then the APIs would be the only way (via an AWS code SDK or CLI).

## Regarding "Save As"

At the time of writing this, there is no way to, via the APIs, create an analysis. So, unfortunately, I think you're out of luck on this point.

You can create dashboards using either existing analyses or dashboards as the source, but I have a feeling this isn't as robust as you're looking for (since you won't be able to change the analysis). To do this, you can use the [`create-template`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/create-dashboard.html) API then then the [`create-dashboard` API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/create-dashboard.html).

## Regarding Sharing

To shared dashboards via the API you can use [`update-dashboard-permissions`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/quicksight/update-dashboard-permissions.html). Unfortunately, as in the case of "Save As", there's no way to share analyses via the API.

Answer (score 0):

If you only need help creating a analysis from a dashboard here's some steps:

- Go into the dashboard
- At the top right, click the Share icon (it looks like 3 dots in a less-than symbol)
- Click share dashboard
- Slide the slider to Allow save as
- Click Confirm
- Click link in the top left that says "<- Go back to xxxxx" (go back to your dashboard)
- Press F5 in your browser to reload your dashboard and get the floppy disk icon to show up
- Click floppy disk icon to save dashboard as an analysis